# Pop-up window not getting the focus

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, window-focus

In Excel 2019, I am having a problem with pop-up window focus when using <kbd>ALT</kbd> shortcuts.

If I open Format Cells window using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (or open it using mouse) focus is just fine but when I open it using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, then opened window does not get the focus at all or gets it with a delay.

The same problem happens with other <kbd>ALT</kbd> pop-up windows as well. Like, paste special, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Anyone had this issue? Do you guys have any solution, recommendation etc.?

Happening for couple days. I have restarted windows, excel. Wanted to ask before re-installing Excel 2019.

Comment: Which program got the focus? If it's not evident, try the [Window Focus Logger](https://www.adminscope.com/downloads/window-focus-logger/) (GUI version).

Comment: @harrymc A-ha. Didn't know about this tool. TIL. After using it, it turns out Google Drive File Stream gets the focus in between menu pop-up. Terminating the Google Drive File Stream process, solved this issue.

Comment: Also found this unanswered thread https://support.google.com/drive/thread/12219608 mentioning GDFS & window focus.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry for comment spam&bothering, since I am new to the community need to ask. Should I close/self answer (or if you want, you can add an answer as well) this question as ""Terminating the GDFS solved the issue"" or edit the question as ""Is there a way to prevent GDFS messing with window focus?"" ?

Comment: You do as you wish with your post. However, usually one invites the person whose comment solved the problem to put up the answer, so it can be accepted (V icon) and/or upvoted (up-arrow sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good tool for finding focus stealers is the free
[Window Focus Logger](https://www.adminscope.com/downloads/window-focus-logger/).

Using the GUI version `WindowFocusLoggerGUI.exe` worked better for me than the
batch version.

[image]

With this tool, the poster located the focus thief, which turned out to be
Google Drive File Stream, and terminating it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Disable this option in GDFS preferences:

```
Show who is editing Office files, and share with other editors if I am editing
```

[image: GDFS Preferences]

It worked for me.

Credit: Matlab Samurai's response in [MS Answers - Paste Special Shortcut Not Working (ALT + E + S)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/paste-special-shortcut-not-working-alt-e-s/4f29f986-a9bf-4f72-942c-4625fd21d664?page=2)